# in the equation y = 4*sin(z*x) where z is a constant , why in certain values of z super-position is observed?

Tags: wave-equation

when a graph of the equation 
y= 4* sin(x) is drawn the graph looks like [result of a graphical calculator when given this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtZhu.png)

it looks like a , normal harmonic wave 
but when the equation y= 4 sin(90*x) is drawn on a graph the wave looks like a super-position [result of a graphing calculator when given this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTaVm.png)

and at y=4*sin(100000x) the super position is not observed .

Comment: ...and $y=4*sin(100000x)$ looks more solid?

Answer (score 0):

That's just a result of the graphics.